# stuck on error with practice round function code

Tags: python

## Basic code using the round() function along with print and input

```
fullName= input("Enter your first and last name: ")    
print("Hello, " + fullName + " nice to meet you")    
Age= input("How old are you: ")    
print("Wow, you're actually " + Age + " years old!? ")    
print("I will now move onto grabbing information and round functions")    
milesdrivenA= input("How many miles did you drive to point A? ")    
milesdrivenB= input("How many miles did you drive to point B? ")    
gallonsusedA= input("How many gallons did you use to point A? ")    
gallonsusedB= input("How many gallons did you use to point B? ")    
totalMiles= str(milesdrivenA + milesdrivenB)    
totalGallons= str(gallonsusedA + gallonsusedB)    
mpg= round(totalMiles / totalGallons, 2)
```

Error:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
> ```

Excuse all the extra things such as "wow you're this years old" it's honestly for extra practice in a way ( the more code i write the more familiar i'll get with what i'm doing).

Now on to my question in the above code, what am i doing wrong? Might be a pretty straight forward answer but i'm truly super beginner so i don't know what exactly what i'm missing. i've tried things such as changing `totalMiles = ^` what's above to  `totalMiles= str( int(milesdrivenA + milesdrivenB ))`. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: "_Excuse all the extra things_": You are encouraged to produce a MINIMAL example when posting your question. The more irrelevant detail your code has, the less likely that you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you converted your `int`s to `str` then attemped to perfom math to them, make them `int`s to do division

@DYZ stated we can go straight into `int` and never have them as `str` to begin with

```
totalMiles= int(milesdrivenA + milesdrivenB)

totalGallons= int(gallonsusedA + gallonsusedB)

mpg= round(totalMiles / totalGallons, 2)
```

> ```
> mpg:  21.25
> ```

Comment: Perhaps not convert them to strings in the first place?

Comment: @DYZ agree, but I didn't know maybe OP wanted them as strings for something later on, some people like there numbers as ints? O.o :)

Comment: @DYZ updated alternative going straight to `int` no `str` involved

Comment: The conversion to `int` is not necessary (and probably harmful).

Comment: @DYZ removed example demonstrating OP use of `str`